# Ignore first word from the line in c

Tags: c

I am working on a code and need some help.

There is a line which needs to be read from a file. The first word must be ignored and the remaining characters (white spaces included) have to be stored into variable. How do I do it?

Comment: `scanf("%*s ");` then followed by `fgets`, it will remove the white spaces following the first word. If you want to preserve it, `scanf("%*s);`

Comment: read line and store in variable, then remove first word.

Comment: nhahtdh, could you please post one examplee, I tried what you said, but no good result.  Dev, I read from line using fgets, store it to the variable using strcpy, but then, how do I remove the first word?

Comment: @Jack Jackson although it's not related to what you asked..in order to notify a previous commenter, mention their user name prefixed with `@` symbol so `nhahtdh` becomes `@nhahtdh` and then only he can listen..

Comment: @nhahtdh, could you please post one examplee, I tried what you said, but no good result.

Comment: @Dev, I read from line using fgets, store it to the variable using strcpy, but then, how do I remove the first word?

Comment: @JackJackson: I have posted an example reading from stream and remove first word.

Answer (score 2):

This will work if your word has no spaces in front of it and you use white space (' ') as separating character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[80];
    char storage[80];
    fgets(buffer, 80, stdin); // enter: »hello nice world!\n«
    char *rest = strchr(buffer, ' '); // rest becomes » nice world!\n«

    printf("rest:   »%s«\n", rest); // » nice world!\n«
    printf("buffer: »%s«\n", buffer); // »hello nice world!\n«

    strncpy( storage, rest, 80 ); // storage contains now » nice world!\n«
    printf("storage: »%s«\n", storage); // » nice world!\n«

    // if you'd like the separating character after the "word" to be any white space
    char *rest2 = buffer;
    rest2 += strcspn( buffer, " \t\r\n" ); // rest2 points now too to » nice world!\n«
    printf("rest2:  »%s«\n", rest2); // » nice world!\n«

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some examples. Read the comments in the program to understand the effect. This will assume that words are delimited by whitespace characters (as defined by `isspace()`). Depending on your definition of "word", the solution may differ.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char rest[1000];
    // Remove first word and consume all space (ASCII = 32) characters
    // after the first word
    // This will work well even when the line contains only 1 word.
    // rest[] contains only characters from the same line as the first word.
    scanf("%*s%*[ ]");
    fgets(rest, sizeof(rest), stdin);
    printf("%s", rest);

    // Remove first word and remove all whitespace characters as
    // defined by isspace()
    // The content of rest will be read from next line if the current line
    // only has one word.
    scanf("%*s ");
    fgets(rest, sizeof(rest), stdin);
    printf("%s", rest);

    // Remove first word and leave spaces after the word intact.
    scanf("%*s");
    fgets(rest, sizeof(rest), stdin);
    printf("%s", rest);

    return 0;
}
```